# Get sentence after pattern with regex python

Tags: python, regex

In my string (example adopted from [this turorial](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/regex/regular-expressions-in-python)) I want to get everything until the first following `.` after the generic `(year).` pattern:

```
str = 'purple alice@google.com, (2002).blah monkey. (1991).@abc.com blah dishwasher'
```

I think I'm almost there with my code but not quite yet:

```
test = re.findall(r'[\(\d\d\d\d\).-]+([^.]*)', str)
```

... which returns: `['com, (2002)', 'blah monkey', ' (1991)', '@abc', 'com blah dishwasher']`

The desired output is:

`['blah monkey', '@abc']`

In other words, I want to find everything that is between the year pattern and the next dot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get every thing between `(year).` and the first `.` you can use this:

```
\(\d{4}\)\.([^.]*)
```

See <kbd>[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zL0hP7/1)</kbd>.

And explanation here:

```
"\(\d{4}\)\.([^.]*)"g

\( matches the character ( literally
  \d{4} match a digit [0-9]
    Quantifier: {4} Exactly 4 times
       \) matches the character ) literally
         \. matches the character . literally
1st Capturing group ([^.]*)
    [^.]* match a single character not present in the list below
        Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        . the literal character .
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
```

Comment: Good solution (+1). Additionally, I like your `Live Demo` buttons (just sneaked into your markup code ;-))

Comment: @Jan easy design. I should script that btw ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `[...]` in the wrong way. Try with `\(\d{4}\)\.([^.]*)\.`:

```
>>> s = 'purple alice@google.com, (2002).blah monkey. (1991).@abc.com blah dishwasher'
>>> re.findall(r'\(\d{4}\)\.([^.]*)\.', s)
['blah monkey', '@abc']
```

For the reference, `[...]` specifies a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). By using `[\(\d\d\d\d\).-]` you were saying: one of `0123456789().-`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
print re.findall(r'\(\d{4}\)\.([^\.]+)', str)
$ ['blah monkey', '@abc']
```